# Building Source Code on Raspberry Pi

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, raspberry-pi, raspbian

This is probably a stupid question, but I have been pouring over forums and google for hours and I can't figure this out. 
I recently downloaded the mame4all source repository from here

https://code.google.com/p/mame4all-pi/

and made a few edits to the list of games that are available. Now I am having issues compiling/building the source. In the repository, there is of course the source code (Contained in an src folder). I cannot figure our how to build/install the source code now that I have edited it. In the main folder there is a makefile.rpi file, makefile.gp2x, and makefile.rpi.debug, I feel like there is something that I need to do with these but I am not entirely sure

I am not sure how to build/compile this source code to test the changes, I am on a raspberry pi using Raspbian Wheezy. I feel like I am missing something simple, any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried `make -f makefile.rpi`?

Comment: make: Warning: File 'src/rpi/rpi.mak' has modification time 7.8e+06s in the future followed by make: *** [obj_mame_rpi] Segmentation Fault

Comment: What a friendly error messsage ;-) 7.8e+06 seconds ... Try setting the system time.

Comment: Tried to, I still recieve the same error message, I may not have set the time properly though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need build tools for ARM architecture installed within the Raspbian Wheezy. But compiling in Raspberry Pi is horribly slow and you might want to do it on your PC instead. If you have a Debian on Ubuntu installation on your PC, then get ARM tool chain that can 'cross-compile' from x86 to ARM. I am sure there is a version of GCC out there than can do this. A simple Google search might provide more details regarding that. Once you get the binary compiled, copy it to the raspberry pi either via SFTP or by connecting the SD card to your PC.

http://qt-project.org/wiki/RaspberryPi_Beginners_guide contains a lot of information and links to download tools for this purpose. In fact, Qt creator can automate most of the tasks and you can deploy compiled binary directly to the Pi from Qt creator.

Comment: Thank you for the insight, I will try this later on today!